# Ionic 3 Accordion List with a Native Element Chart

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, charts, ionic3

I am trying to make an accordion list where when a user clicks on it, and it then displays a chart of data. The problem is the chart shows originally, but when I close the accordion list then it doesn't show again upon reopening. So basically open app, shows chart, click accordion element, chart disappears, click accordion element, it expands, but the chart doesn't show.

chart-page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Health Summary</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item padding (click)="toggleChartThisWeek(thisWeek)">
      This Week
      <div *ngIf="thisWeek">
        <br>
        <canvas #lineCanvas></canvas>
        <br>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

chart-page.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chart-page',
  templateUrl: 'chart-page.html',
})
export class ChartPage {


  @ViewChild('lineCanvas') lineCanvas;
  lineChart: any;
  chartLabels: any = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  chartData: any = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
  thisWeek: any = true;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HealthSummaryPage');
        this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {

            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: this.chartLabels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 1,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data: this.chartData,
                        spanGaps: false,
                    }
                ]
            }

        });
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
  }

  toggleChartThisWeek() {
    if(this.thisWeek) {
      this.thisWeek = false;
    } else {
      this.thisWeek = true;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get it to appear every time? Do I need to store it into a variable, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below which hopefully forces angular to redraw the template fully:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chart-page',
  templateUrl: 'chart-page.html',
})
export class ChartPage {


  @ViewChild('lineCanvas') lineCanvas;
  lineChart: any;
  chartLabels: any = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  chartData: any = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
  thisWeek: any = true;


  constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public navParams: NavParams,
      public platform: Platform) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter() HealthSummaryPage');
  }

  drawChart(){
    if (! this.lineCanvas) { return; }
    this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: this.chartLabels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: this.chartData,
                    spanGaps: false,
                }
            ]
        }
    });
}

  toggleChartThisWeek() {
    if(this.thisWeek) {
      this.thisWeek = false;
    } else {
      this.thisWeek = true;
      this.drawChart();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I get the error:
`Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

Comment: Give it another shot. I changed `ionViewDidLoad()` -> `ionViewDidEnter()` and added an the `if (! this.lineCanvas) { return; }` in `drawChart()`.

Comment: Now it isn't erroring out, but it still isn't showing.